# UITableViewCell does not display text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have 3 sections in my TableView and want to display different information on it. I have created two Nib Files. One of it has a label and the other one a button.

The problem is that the cells only show the placeholer text ("Label" & "Button"). 
I tried to leave the placeholder empty but still does not work..
"cellButton" and "cellText" are the cells. "buttonCell" and "productLabel" are my labels.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CustomCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"ButtonCell";

    CustomCell *cellText;
    ButtonCell *cellButton;


    cellText = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellButton = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cellButton.buttonCell.titleLabel.text = arraySection1[indexPath.row];
        return cellButton;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cellText.productLabel.text = arraySection2[indexPath.row];
        return cellText;
    }

    else {
        cellButton.buttonCell.titleLabel.text = arraySection3[indexPath.row];
        return cellButton;
    }
}
```

This are my nibs:

```
UINib *customCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
[infoTableView registerNib:customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

UINib *buttonCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ButtonCell" bundle:nil];
[infoTableView registerNib:buttonCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"];
```

Comment: Did you set the Data Source?

Comment: DateSource and Delegate are set. The protocols are implemented.

Comment: The labels and buttons outlets are connected to their respective properties, right? Did you register the nibs?

Comment: Yes, the Labels and buttons are connected to their properties and the nibs are registered

Comment: Can you add some break points on each `return` line and check if each table cell is going thru the correct path you expected?

Comment: Now the app has crashed
"Thread 1: breakpoint 1:1"

Comment: I would check if cellText and cellButton are not nil (probably you would like to dequeue just the necessary cell what you will be using later)

Comment: They shouldn't be `nil`. If the table cannot dequeue one, it should automatically alloc a new one. @DavidP, where exactly did it crash?

Comment: Both were nil. I created properties but it does not work

Comment: It crashed right at the breakpoint (is this what you mean? - i am a objective c beginner)

Comment: Show us the lines where you registered the nib, please.

Comment: By the way: both nibs are registered in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Ok, that is right. Try this code: http://pastebin.com/pQ3ew7s7. This way, only one cell is dequeued.

Comment: Now the labels show their text but the buttons are still empty

Comment: This might help: When the view loads the text for the buttons is set, but just in the next moment the button title is "Button"

Comment: Try using [cellButton.buttonCell setTitle:arraySection1[indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; to set the title of your button.

Answer (score 0):

While setting text for `UIButton` or `UILabel` don't try to set the string directly from `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Set the string data as follows:

```
button.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array[indexOfObject];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array[indexOfObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible to have two nibs in one cell.

When I do this I used to have only one nib.

Have you tried that?